# Serenity test error element not available in headless mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless, serenity-bdd

The scenario is:

I have serenity tests that i launch with chromedriver that work 
When i launch the tests without headless option the tests are "passed"
while with the headless mode the tests are failed with error: 
**net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: The following error occurred: Timed out after 5 seconds. Element not available**

here the line command that launch the test : **mvn clean verify -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome**

And the serenity.properties:

- webdriver.chrome.driver = chromedriver
- webdriver.base.url= ********
- webdriver.timeouts.implicitlywait=5000
- chrome.switches=--headless;
- serenity.browser.maximized = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add in chrome.switches --window-size=1920,1080;

- chrome.switches=--window-size=1920,1080;--headless;

Comment: What does `serenity.browser.maximized = true` does?

Comment: serenity.browser.maximized = true should open the browser to the maximum size but it seems that it is only counted in the case of launch without headless mode

Comment: Tried this solution using chrome.switches=--window-size=900,600;--headless; which is the resolution used without the headless mode and on where the test cases are passing, but the issue still happens to me. Using chrome + chrome driver 108. Additional ideas ? Could be a bug into the selenium web driver for windows ?